# How to remove or edit for example width of "Group" name from header in v-table in Vuetify 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

How to remove or edit for example width of "Group" name from header in v-table in Vuetify 3

[image]

[example code playground from doc](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the header as blank, add a new object to the `headers` array with key `data-table-group`. This is the header object for the "Group" header.  If you don't provide a `title` property it will effectively hide the header. You mentioned possibly editing the width, which is also set in this object with the `width` property

```js
headers: [
  {
    key: 'data-table-group',  // "Group" header
    width: '0px'
  },
  ...
]
```